# How to get value from string with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Suppose I have a url that looks like this:

```
http://mysite/super/id/800
```

The 'super/id' part in the URL is fixed.I am trying to create a compact statement to return the 800 value with lodash. What could be a solution for this. I know how to split it up into an array and then get it from there but just looking for a more elegant solution?

Comment: Will it always be the last part of the string?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Is `string.split('/').pop()` not acceptable? In my opinion using native javascript is the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: awesome that works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not lodash I would argue that given the `800` portion of the string is certain to be the final part, the following is cleanest.

```
string.split('/').pop();
```

It's best (in my opinion) to avoid using frameworks and libraries unless there is a deficit in the language requiring you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating an array, you could try using `String#slice` and `String#lastIndexOf`:

```js
var string = 'http://mysite/super/id/800'

console.log(
  string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) //=> '800'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try Regular Expressions**
Your url seems to be a good candidate.

```
var url = "http://mysite/super/id/800";
var pattern = /\d+$/;

var match = pattern.exec(url);
// ["800"], it will be null if there was no match
```